# Given $~ {a,b,c \ge 0 ~ , ~ a+b+c=1 } ~ $ then prove $~ {\sum\limits_{cyc} \sqrt{a+b^2 } \geqslant 2 } $

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Given  $~ a,b,c \ge 0  ~ , ~ a+b+c=1  ~ $, prove that
> $$\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{a+b^2 } := \sqrt{a + b^2} + \sqrt{b + c^2} + \sqrt{c + a^2}\ge 2.$$

Here's what I've tried : $\sum\limits_{cyc} \sqrt{a+b^2 } = \sum\limits_{cyc} \sqrt{\sqrt a^2 +b^2 }=\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt a^2 +b^2 )(1^2 +1^2 ) } \ge \\ \ge \sum\limits_{cyc} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{a} +b )^2 }=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (1+ \sqrt a +\sqrt b + \sqrt c ). $

Any ideas how to proceed  and  am I on the right  track ?

Comment: What do you mean by $cyc$?

Comment: cyc means cyclic sum.

Comment: This is leading nowhere. Because the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality you are using does not preserve equality. You can see by substituting $a=1, b=c=0$ into $\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt a^2 +b^2 )(1^2 +1^2 ) } \ge \sum\limits_{cyc} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{a} +b )^2 }$, the $LHS > RHS$

Comment: A possibly simple way to proceed with simple cyclic inequalities (I mean the conditions does not look too bulky to hand-calculate) is to set $f(a,b,c)= \sqrt{a + b^2} + \sqrt{b + c^2} + \sqrt{c + a^2}$, and prove that $f(a,b,c) \ge f(a, \frac{1-a}2, \frac{1-a}2), \forall 0<b,c<1-a $. You will later have an one-variable inequality, which can be easily solved using differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG, assume that $a = \max(a, b, c)$.

It suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 \sqrt{a + b^2} + \sqrt{a + c^2} &\ge 2a + b + c, \tag{1}\\[6pt]
 \sqrt{b + c^2} + \sqrt{c + a^2} &\ge \sqrt{a + c^2} + b + c. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
(Add them up to get the desired result.)

First, using Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 &(\sqrt{a + b^2} + \sqrt{a + c^2})^2 - (2a + b + c)^2\\
 =\,& a + b^2 + a + c^2 + 2\sqrt{(a + b^2)(a + c^2)} - (2a + b + c)^2\\
 \ge\,& a + b^2 + a + c^2 + 2(a + bc) - (2a + b + c)^2\\
 =\,& 4a(1 - a - b - c)\\
 =\,& 0.
\end{align*}
Thus, (1) is true.

Second, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\sqrt{b + c^2} + \sqrt{c + a^2} - \sqrt{a + c^2} - b - c\\
 =\,& [\sqrt{b + c^2} - (b + c)] - (\sqrt{a + c^2} - \sqrt{c + a^2})\\
 =\,& \frac{b(1 - b - 2c)}{\sqrt{b + c^2} + b + c} - \frac{(a - c)(1 - a - c)}{\sqrt{a + c^2} + \sqrt{c + a^2}}\\
 =\,& \frac{b(a - c)}{\sqrt{b + c^2} + b + c} - \frac{(a - c)b}{\sqrt{a + c^2} + \sqrt{c + a^2}}\\
 \ge\,& 0
\end{align*}
where we have used $\sqrt{a+c^2} \ge \sqrt{b+c^2}$ and
$(c+a^2) - (b+c)^2 = (c+a^2) - (1-a)^2 = c + 2a - 1 = a - b \ge 0$ (so $\sqrt{c+a^2} \ge b + c$).
Thus, (2) is true.

We are done.

Answer (score 2):

COMMENT.- A method to solve these inequalities graphically. Leaving fixed $a$, we have to study the relative position of the line $L: x + y = 1-a$ with respect to the curve
$$\Gamma: \sqrt{a+x^2}+\sqrt{x+y^2}+\sqrt{y+a^2}=2$$
where $0\lt a, x, y \lt1$. which is decreasing in the first quadrant because $\dfrac{dy}{ dx}\lt 0$.

$L$ is tangent to $\Gamma$  at the point $(\frac13,\frac13)$ and it is the only point where it touches the curve ($L$ cannot cut the curve in the first quadrant because if it does then the inequality is false in a certain interval $(x_1, x_2)$ , in other words the line $L$ should be always in top of $\Gamma$ , at most it can be tangent to $\Gamma$). The calculations can be hard in some cases. Anyway this is what happen for all $a$ and it is easily verified graphically.